# MySQL : add data from another database, starting on specific row, user_id is primary, need to insert incrementing numbers starting from 20

Tags: mysql, insert, row, increment

I have an user table with 19 rows (first row is admin). I need to add more, so I have another database with a table having more than 1.400.000 users.

My table has an "user_id" as primary key, INT(11), no auto-increment. I need to add users starting in row 20, and only "first_name", "last_name" and "email".

My first try:

**INSERT INTO mydatabase.users (first_name, last_name, email) SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM anotherdatabase.users**

That gets me a *"Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value"*.

I understand it is because user_id is primary key and cannot be null. So, again, it is int(11), non auto-increment.

So I want to add 20,21,22,23 and so on, along the other data. I searched a lot for about 5 hours and can´t seem to find anything I can understand.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use auto_increment?

Comment: Because I´m managing it from my php code. Our teacher asked us not to use auto_increment.

Comment: If php is pertinent to the question you should include a php tag.

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to make my question as clean as possible, but good point.

Answer (score 1):

To get your numbers starting from 20:

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase.users (user_id, first_name, last_name, email) 
  SELECT 19+row_number() over (),
         first_name, 
         last_name, 
         email 
  FROM anotherdatabase.users
```

**19+row_number() over ()**
'row_number()' = Number of current row within its partition (Mysql documentation)
'over ()' - defines a partition without condition; so in fact counts for the entire table

Details for both can be found under [MySQL Window Function concepts and syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) 
19+ - ...

Alternatively - if the MySQL version < 8.0:

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase.users (user_id, first_name, last_name, email) 
  SELECT (select 20+count(*) 
          from  anotherdatabase.users u1 where u1.id < u.id) as id,
         first_name, 
         last_name, 
         email 
  FROM anotherdatabase.users u
```

This does rather assume that you have a user_id on the other table as well.
The inner select just counts how many records are in the original database that have a smaller id than the record that is being returned at that point (and adds 20 to have the numbering start at 20).

And a third option (not depending on the existence of user_id):

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase.users (user_id, first_name, last_name, email) 
  SELECT ( @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS user_id,
         first_name, 
         last_name, 
         email 
  FROM anotherdatabase.users u,
       (SELECT @row_num:=19) var;
```

I'm not a great fan of this as it involves creation of variables to keep track of the row number.

Comment: Window function are available from version  8.0.

Comment: Did not work :(

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(),
         first_name,
         last_name,
         email
  FROM anotherdatabase.users' at line 2

Mysql version is 5.7.21

Comment: @P.Salmon well caught.  Thanks

Comment: anotherdatabase.users does not have an user_id. It just contains names and email. This turned out to be a quite hard query. I really apreciate the effort

Comment: Found a much simpler solution. I can not believe it. I mean, I barely know mysql, and here in Stackoverflow I consider this as the elite of each area. Thank you so much for your help. It helped me find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Write a procedure that use variable. for i < 1400020 , you would need to count the number of rows in anotherdatabase.users then add the figure with 20.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_test_data()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 20;

  WHILE i < 1400020 DO
   INSERT INTO mydatabase.users (user_id, first_name, last_name, email) 
   SELECT i,first_name, last_name,  email  FROM anotherdatabase.users;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL insert_test_data();
DROP PROCEDURE insert_test_data;
```

Comment: Woah. I didn´t learn stored procedures, but I´m taking this answer as future reference for learning.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way, using variables. I still can´t believe it. It worked like a charm

```
SET @i=19;
INSERT INTO mydatabase.users(user_id, first_name, last_name, email) 
         SELECT @i:=@i+1,
         first_name, 
         last_name, 
         email 
FROM anotherdatabase.users;
```

Comment: You could also cross join (select @i:=19) as i - which would be slightly neater and is the more normal approach for mysql row_number simulation. I have to say I don't see the point of having an id column at all.

Comment: Yes, but I was asked to put an user_id. There is a unique person document number in my country, perfect for primary key, but no. Not allowed.